# Getting SQL query Syntax error or access violation while running raw SQL in yii2

Tags: mysql, sql, yii, yii2

am trying to creating a search function to be able to search for products and also filter the result by relevance but i got  Syntax error after the query.
below is the error i got too

```
 sql error
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mens', 'winter', 'jacket'%',6,0) + if (title LIKE '%'mens'%',5,0) + if (title LI' at line 5
The SQL being executed was: SELECT p.product_id,p.title,p.price,p.unit_sold,
p.profile_img,p.store_name,p.item_number,
(
(-- Title score
if (title LIKE '%'mens', 'winter', 'jacket'%',6,0) + if (title LIKE '%'mens'%',5,0) + if (title LIKE '%'winter'%',5,0) + if (title LIKE '%'jacket'%',5,0)
)+
(-- description
if (description LIKE '%'mens', 'winter', 'jacket'%',5,0) + if (description LIKE '%'mens'%',4,0) + if (description LIKE '%'winter'%',4,0) + if (description LIKE '%'jacket'%',4,0)
)

) as relevance
FROM products p
WHERE p.is_active = '1'
HAVING relevance > 0
ORDER BY relevance DESC,p.unit_sold DESC
LIMIT 10
```

and the search function

```
function search($q){
            if (mb_strlen(trim($q))===0){
                // no need for empty search
                return false; 
            }
            $query = $this->limitChars(trim($q));

            // Weighing scores
            $scoreFullTitle = 6;
            $scoreTitleKeyword = 5;
            $scoreFullDescription = 5;
            $scoreDescriptionKeyword = 4;

            $keywords = $this->filterSearchKeys($query);
            $escQuery = $this->escape($keywords); 
            $titleSQL = array();
            $descSQL = array();

            /** Matching full occurences **/
            if (count($keywords) > 1){
                $titleSQL[] = "if (title LIKE '%".$escQuery."%',{$scoreFullTitle},0)";
                $descSQL[] = "if (description LIKE '%".$escQuery."%',{$scoreFullDescription},0)";

            /** Matching Keywords **/
            foreach($keywords as $key){
                $titleSQL[] = "if (title LIKE '%".Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($key)."%',{$scoreTitleKeyword},0)";
                $descSQL[] = "if (description LIKE '%".Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($key)."%',{$scoreDescriptionKeyword},0)";
            }

            //add 0 is query string is empty to avoid error
            if (empty($titleSQL)){
                $titleSQL[] = 0;
            }
            if (empty($descSQL)){
                $descSQL[] = 0;
            }
            $sql = "SELECT p.product_id,p.title,p.price,p.unit_sold,
                    p.profile_img,p.store_name,p.item_number,
                    (
                        (-- Title score
                        ".implode(" + ", $titleSQL)."
                        )+
                        (-- description
                        ".implode(" + ", $descSQL)." 
                        )

                    ) as relevance
                    FROM products p
                    WHERE p.is_active = '1'
                    HAVING relevance > 0
                    ORDER BY relevance DESC,p.unit_sold DESC
                    LIMIT 10";
            $results = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
            if (!$results){
                return false;
            }
            return $results;
        }
```

I'm also using escape() method to escape the query string in other to avoid sql injection but am not so convince this is the best practice as what the escape method does is adding single quote around the string which in turn will not even return any match in the table, I also try to use mysqli_escape_string() but can't get it work either, so i want to know what's the best practice in Yii2 to escape query string and avoid sql injection attack.

```
function escape($values)
        {
                $values = (array)$values;
                $escaped = array();
                foreach($values as $value) {
                        if(!is_scalar($value)) {
                                throw new CException('One of the values passed to values() is not a scalar.');
                        }
                        $escaped[] = Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($value);
                }
                return implode(', ', $escaped);
        }
```

Comment: What query are you want to achieve?

Comment: @everyone thanks to everyone but i've been able to solve the problem it was cause by the single quote created by Yii::$app->db->quoteValue($value); and after removing the funtion it works goods

Comment: Without it you're vulnerable to SQL Injection, so you probably just shot yourself in the foot...

Comment: @rob006 yes you're perfectly right and am still searching but having got a perfect way to escape the query string to avoid SQL injection, since with the quoteValue($value) method the code won't work so i need a way to escape it i tried mysqli_escape_string(); but can't make it work as i need a connection and i prodive Yii::$app->db but got error that the first arg was suppose to be mysqli but object was passed, please is there any workaround against this problem, i know i'm not going to leave it like that because it's prong to attack but i remove it to be sure where the error comes from,

Comment: And you still did not explained how this query should look like and didn't share this "working" code. You need something like `if (title LIKE '%mens, winter, jacket%',6,0)`?

Comment: @rob006 i need something like if (title LIKE '%mens, winter, jacket%',6,0) if (title LIKE '%mens%',6,0) if (title LIKE '% winter%',6,0) if (title LIKE '%jacket%',6,0) thanks

Comment: @rob006 i need something like if (title LIKE '%mens, winter, jacket%',6,0) if (title LIKE '%mens%',6,0) if (title LIKE '% winter%',6,0) if (title LIKE '%jacket%',6,0) is there a way i can make this code work without removing the quoteValue($value) method, i tried something like thistitle LIKE ".Yii::$app->db->quoteValue("%".$key."%"),{$scoreTitleKeyword},0)";  but still the single qoute are still there preventing it to work and getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the whole expression for `LIKE`, including `%` wildcards:

```
$value = Yii::$app->db->quoteValue('%' . implode(', ', (array) $keywords) . '%');
$titleSQL[] = "if (title LIKE $value,$scoreFullTitle,0)";
```

This will generate something like:

```
if (title LIKE '%mens, winter, jacket%',6,0)
```